# Rails 3: How to show stack trace in server logs for 500 Internal Server Error while in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Other posts on SO explain how to show stack traces in views while in production, but what if we want the errors to appear in the server logs? What is the right way to accomplish this?

We're using Rails 3.2.12.

Answer (score 1):

[Log levels](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.19/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels), which is mentioned in the guides.

> The default Rails log level is `info` in production mode and `debug` in
>   development and test mode.
>
> To change the default log level, use
>
> `config.log_level = :warn # In any environment initializer`

So, apparently, you need to modify your `production` environment initializer config to use `:debug` log level.

However, this will cause logs to grow rapidly. If you encounter bugs, you should be solving them in development mode. In production it's common to tune the app just to fail silently with not-so-descriptive error message in case of an error. For hunting down environment-specific bugs, [it's suggested](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#staging-like-prod) to use a `production`-like `staging` enviromnent.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to provide stack traces only on certain types of errors, e.g., 500 errors?

Comment: @Crashalot not sure, error 500 is an answer to a large number of problems. You could rescue specific exceptions in controller and print stack trace explicitly (I guess?) as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260778/rails-3-customizing-the-error-404-pages